# extract multiple records on one column?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I wrote this query but I can't get the result I want

```sql
SELECT pr.* as profil, (select count(*) from t_employe e where e.profil_id = pr.id) as nbEmploye, f.* as fonctionnalites
FROM t_profil pr, t_fonctionnalite f
INNER JOIN t_profils_fonctionnalites pf ON  pf.fonctionnalite_id = f.id 
WHERE pf.profil_id = pr.id
GROUP BY f.id, pr.id
```

```
1   "CODEP1"    "descriptionP1" "labelP1"       20      1   "codeF1"    "descriptionF1" "labelF1"
2   "CODEP2"    "descriptionP2" "labelP2"       1       1   "codeF1"    "descriptionF1" "labelF1"
1   "CODEP1"    "descriptionP1" "labelP1"       20      2   "codeF2"    "descriptionF2" "labelF2"
...
```

I want to get:

```
1   "CODEP1"    "descriptionP1" "labelP1"       20      1   "codeF1"    "descriptionF1" "labelF1"
                                                        2   "codeF2"    "descriptionF2" "labelF2"
2   "CODEP2"    "descriptionP2" "labelP2"       1       1   "codeF1"    "descriptionF1" "labelF1"
...
```

the goal is to have this result in json:

```
[
  {
    "profil": {
                "code": "CODEP1,
                "label": "LABELP1,
                "description": "DESCRIPTIONP1,
              },
    "nbEmploye": 20,
    "fonctionalites": [
       {
                "code": "CODEF1,
                "label": "LABELF1,
                "description": "DESCRIPTIONF1,
       },  
       {
                "code": "CODEF2,
                "label": "LABELF2,
                "description": "DESCRIPTIONF2,
       },               
    ],
    "employe": {        //  <-----------   
                  "name": "........."
               }

  }
]
```

how to do ? I put the initial request at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Having the definition of your tables would be better.

Try something like this :

```
SELECT ARRAY(
SELECT jsonb_build_object( 'profil', jsonb_build_object('code', pr.code, 'label', pr.label, 'description', pr.description)
                         , 'nbEmployee', count(DISTINCT e.name)
                         , 'fonctionalites', jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('code', f.code, 'label', f.label, 'description', f.description))
                         , 'employee', jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('name', e.name))
                         )
  FROM t_profils_fonctionnalites pf
 INNER JOIN t_profil pr
    ON pr.id = pf.profil_id
 INNER JOIN t_fonctionnalite f
    ON f.id = pf.fonctionnalite_id
 INNER JOIN employee e
    ON e.profil_id = pr.id
GROUP BY pr
) :: jsonb
```